# Getline not recognized by compiler

Tags: c++, getline

I have just started C++ after working with C for almost a year. I'm writing a program for a user to input info about a song. I read that I should use getline() to read strings with spaces. Here is my code:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    typedef struct Song
    {
        char title[20];
        char album[20];
        char artist[20];
        int year;
    } song;

    //store song info
    Song Input;
    char inputStr[20];
    int inputYear;
    cout << "Enter the name of a song: ";
    getline(cin, inputStr);
    strcpy(Input.title, inputStr);
    cout << "Enter the album of your song: ";
    getline(cin, inputStr);
    strcpy(Input.album, inputStr);
    cout << "Enter the artist of your song: ";
    getline(cin, inputStr);
    strcpy(Input.artist, inputStr);
    cout << "Enter the year your song was released: ";
    cin >> inputYear;
    Input.year = inputYear;

    //print
    cout << "Song title: " << Input.title << endl;
    cout << "From album: " << Input.album << endl;
    cout << "Artist: " << Input.artist << endl;
    cout << "Released: " << Input.year << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My compiler<sup>1</sup> throws 3 errors, one for each of the `getline()` calls, not recognizing `getline()` despite the fact I have `#include <string>`. I have looked up sample usage of the `getline()` function.

Thanks for any help.

<sup>1</sup>*I have wondered if this problem might concern an issue with the standard of C++ that my compiler supports. I did a bit of research and I did not find anything that helped me learn which standard I am using. Here's some info:*

I'm using Terminal on Mac.
After `g++ version`:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Cont.../usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
```

These lines seem to be the only ones of use here, but I could give more info. If someone has any idea which standard of C++ this is, whether it's C++11, or C++14, or otherwise, that would also be very helpful. Thanks again.

**UPDATE**:
started from scratch, tried to take as much of your advice as possible while still sticking to some of what I know. No errors and works just as I hoped. Thanks for all your help.
New code:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

struct Song
{
    string title;
    string artist;
    string album;
    string year;
}song;

int main()
{
    Song Input;
    cout << "Song? ";
    getline(cin, Input.title);
    cout << "Artist? ";
    getline(cin, Input.artist);
    cout << "Album? ";
    getline(cin, Input.album);
    cout << "Year? ";
    getline(cin, Input.year);

    cout << "Song: " << Input.title << endl;
    cout << "Artist: " << Input.artist << endl;
    cout << "Album: " << Input.album << endl;
    cout << "Year: " << Input.year << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _My compiler throws 3 errors_ And those errors were? Most likely they are related to the fact that [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) expects 2nd argument to be `std::string`, not `char[]`. Maybe you wanted to call [`cin.getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline)?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius `error: no matching function for call to 'getline'`

Comment: @TannerCausey The compiler is indeed finding `std::getline`, but it can't find an overload that will accept a `char[]` either directly or through an implicit conversion. You need to read the first few lines, not just the first one.

Comment: @TannerCausey I suspected as much (typically, such error provides more information, than you copied), and the rest of my comment still applies.

Comment: `char` arrays are fine...but if you're using C++ go ahead and jump all in.  Use `std::string` instead.  There are far too many benefits to list here.

Comment: I tried to use a `string` variable instead of `char`, but that caused more errors with my calls of `strlen`. If there is a better/simpler way to accomplish this, please let me know.

Comment: _"I read that I should use getline() to read strings with spaces. Here is my code:"_ More accurately, use getline() to read lines.

Comment: @TannerCausey For starters, should read a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). SO is not tutorial site. Have a look through [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) documentation: what you wanted to use instead of `strlen` is [`length`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) method on a `std::string` object.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I am doing this as practice for a course I am starting in the fall. As for the `strlen` part, I meant `strcpy` - I apologize.

Comment: @TannerCausey If you want to assign strings, use the assignment operator, which is provided for `std::string`. From what I can see - you are trying to learn C, while claiming, that you are learning C++.

Answer (score 5):

The version of getline you are using takes a std::string as a parameter, not an array of char. If you want to use an array of char (and you shouldn't), you need to use the member function version:

```
    cin.getline( some_char_array, array_size );
```

Comment: I am still working to understand members/structures/pointers and the like. Is it the `getline()` function call that is the member of `cin`? Thanks so much!

Comment: It's a member of basic_istream: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline

Comment: (So, basically, yes.)

Answer (score 0):

I would switch from using `char` arrays to using `string`'s everywhere.  For example I would do your code like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct Song{
    std::string title;
    std::string album;
    std::string artist;
    int year;
};

int main()
{    
    //store song info
    Song Input;
    int inputYear;
    std::cout << "Enter the name of a song: ";
    getline(std::cin, Input.title);
    std::cout << "Enter the album of your song: ";
    getline(std::cin, Input.album);
    std::cout << "Enter the artist of your song: ";
    getline(std::cin, Input.artist);
    std::cout << "Enter the year your song was released: ";
    std::cin >> Input.year;

    //print
    std::cout << "Song title: " << Input.title << '\n';
    std::cout << "From album: " << Input.album << '\n';
    std::cout << "Artist: " << Input.artist << '\n';
    std::cout << "Released: " << Input.year << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My preference is to not use `using namespace std;` but there's nothing wrong with it.  Notice that using strings directly I don't need to copy things.  I can use `getline` to do all that for me.  I also don't need to worry about overrunning the size of the `char` array because `string` does that for me as well.

Comment: I'd go further and lose the C-like struct definition, also move it outside of the function